# Exibir o JSON do ng-model como a opção selecionada de um dropdown

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-directives

Olá, eu estou com dúvidas se isso é possível.
Por exemplo, eu tenho um dropdown com um array de JSON de cursos no `ng-options`:

```
<select name="curso" ng-options="curso.cursoId.sigla + ' - ' + curso.cursoId.periodo for curso in cursos" class="form-control" ng-model="disciplina.curso" required>
    <option value="">Selecione o curso</option>
</select>
```

Quando eu vou editar uma disciplina, o `ng-model` `disciplina.curso` já tem um objeto curso, então a ideia é que o curso que está nesse model já apareça selecionado no dropdown quando eu abro o formulário ao invés do "Selecione um curso".

Tem algum recurso do próprio `ng-options` que me permite fazer isso? Ou será necessário criar uma função ou diretiva? Não tenho muita experiência com AngularJS, então não sei bem como proceder.

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Olá amigo para que ele volte selecionado seu controller precisa fornecer o mesmo dado para sua variável disciplina.curso

Comment: Uma forma simples de fazer isso seria definir seu model assim: disciplina.curso = cursos[0].

Comment: Olá @DavidSilva, eu consegui fazer isso utilizando o `track by`, e também publiquei a resolução logo abaixo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui fazer isso usando o `track by`, que nesse caso os identificadores de um curso são a `sigla` e o `periodo`:

```
<select name="curso" ng-options="curso.cursoId.sigla + ' - ' + curso.cursoId.periodo for curso in cursos track by curso.cursoId.sigla + curso.cursoId.periodo" class="form-control" ng-model="disciplina.curso" required disabled>
    <option value="">Selecione o curso</option>
</select>
```

Pelo que eu li sobre, utilizado o id do objeto com o `track by` o Angular utiliza este id como sendo o identificador do objeto no DOM, desta forma ele consegue validar se o objeto que está em `disciplina.curso` é igual a algum dos objetos da lista `cursos`, e se for esse o caso, o dropdown exibirá o objeto do `ng-model` como o selecionado da lista.